# Check if the time difference is less than 1 second in moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, momentjs

In my javascript project, I want to check if the time difference is less than 1 second. I use moment to get this difference. This is the function I have written to achieve it.

```
const withinOneSecond = (time) => {
  const currentTime = moment();
  return time + 1000 < currentTime;
};
```

But this doesn't work as expected. How can I check if the given time is within a second to the current time?

Comment: use moment API, do not add a number to an object... don't you use typescript  to help you doing so ?

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/

Comment: `return time.add(1, 's').isBefore()` (-> https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`moment#diff`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/).
As an example, I've added a second to a date and taking the difference in with `.diff` passing `seconds` as second argument should return the difference in seconds

```js
var a = moment();
var b = moment().add(1, 'seconds');
console.log(b.diff(a, 'seconds'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

The supported measurements are `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds`. [Here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/)

For your particular case, you should be doing something like

```js
const withinOneSecond = (time) => {
  const currentTime = moment();
  return currentTime.diff(time, 'seconds')  == 1
};

var time = moment().add(1, 'seconds');
let results = withinOneSecond(time);

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need moment for this. Use vanilla, use `.getTime()` to get time in milliseconds and compare it with the current time. See the code below:

```js
var date = new Date();

const withinOneSecond = (time) => new Date().getTime() - new Date(time).getTime() < 1000; 

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(withinOneSecond(date)); // true
}, 500)

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(withinOneSecond(date)); // false
}, 1500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the duration.asHours() method ([see the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/)).

```
const withinOneSecond = (time) => {
  const currentTime = moment();
  return moment.duration(currentTime.diff(time)).asSeconds() > 1;
};
```